Is reconstructing a historically accurate Julian Calendar possible?
I understand that after the Julian Calendar took effect in 45 B.C., leap years were mistakenly added every three years rather than every four years. To correct for this, Augustus suspended leap years for a while. The general consensus seems to be that after 9 B.C., A.D. 8 was the next leap year (though some argue that A.D. 4 is when leap years resumed).
Most online Gregorian-to-Julian Calendar Date Converters don't seem to account for this, but instead appear to be proleptic (i.e., they assume that the rule of adding a leap year every four years was always followed correctly and apply this reasoning to stretches of time when this wasn't the case).
For example, AstroPixel's Calendar Date Converter gives February 28, 5 B.C. of the Julian Calendar as a Monday. Though 5 B.C. should've been a leap year in theory, this was supposedly one of the years that omitted the leap day to help get the calendar back on track. If it's true that 5 B.C. was treated as a common year, then wouldn't the day that followed Monday, February 28, 5 B.C. have been Tuesday, March 1, 5 B.C. (as 5 B.C. shouldn't have had a February 29)? Yet, AstroPixel (and most Julian Calendar date converters I've seen) say that February 29, 5 B.C. (which, according to the historical record, probably didn't even exist) was a Tuesday, and give March 1, 5 B.C. as a Wednesday instead.
I know that the dates calculated by these online Julian Calendar Date conversion tools are meant to serve as helpful approximations that we can use to compare theoretical Julian Calendar dates to our modern conception of a 7 Day Week; however, I've used the above example to illustrate the fact that the days of the week and dates of full moons/new moons that we attribute to dates in the Julian calendar during this historical period of irregular leap years must be slightly off since they sometimes add dates that theoretically should've existed but in practice likely didn't to the count .
Is there any online resource or scholarly writing out there that attempts to reconstruct the Julian Calendar while keeping in mind and accounting for the leap year error?
If the answer to the above is no, would it even be possible to take on this task? Is there even enough information left in the historical record to give this a shot? I'm particularly interested in whether there are any historical documents that give the Julian Calendar Date along the lines of "Today is [Day of the week], MM/DD/YY" that might serve as a starting point to work off of. I understand that this would likely come later on, as the Romans reckoned days based on their proximity to either the kalends, nones, or ides. Given that there is a debate about which years actually ended up being leap years during the period of irregular leap years, I also understand that the closest we might be able to get to reconstructing a historically accurate Julian Calendar is making a few different calendar scenarios rather than being able to single out any one that should be favored over another. Thanks for any insight you might have!

About the only ancient dates that can be determined to the day on a proleptic calendar are eclipses, full moons, and maybe solstices/equinoxes.  So I'd look for things of that sort for which the Romans gave a date in a document or inscription that survived. (Full moons may be iffy, since to use them you need to know the Roman/proleptic correspondence to significantly better than two weeks.)

https://www.instonebrewer.com/TyndaleSites/Egypt/ptolemies/chron/roman/167bc_fr.htm tries to do just that. The conversion tables are linked there, and there's an exhaustive discussion on that site of his sources and methods for reconstructing the dates.

Apparently, the authors of the applications know the history of the Julian calendar worse, than you. I cannot see, why you cannot do the correct application or cooperate with somebody on the task. +1 for the most interesting info.
